# Big blind betting in tournaments

Tags: texas-hold-em

You are the big blind, blinds are 1000 and 2000. There is 1 caller. Action is on you, you bet 1 5000 chip on top of your 2000 big blind, saying nothing.

Is this a min raise or a full 5000 raise?

Comment: I think it's pretty clearly a raise to 7000 like Grinch91 says.  What kind of game is this?  home game?  card room?  bar league tournament?

Answer (score 4):

This is a raise to 7000. I'm assuming the dealer or floor ruled it was just a min raise or a call? It's a full raise.

Comment: Yep. "One chip rule" only applies when the player is facing a bet that he must call. Big blind's option is not such a situation, so the chip speaks. Same as the opening bet of a later round.